# Azure Active Directory Custom Fields

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to add custom fields to the Azure AD graph. e.g. lets say I have a field called EmployeeCode which I want to just store my own string property in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

Given Azure Active Directory's multi-tenanted nature, it cannot be natively extended per tenant. However, it can be extended through other means, like using the Windows Azure Graph Store.

Answer (score 0):

'Recent' updates to Azure AD provide support for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn720459.aspx